# How can I place two orders in a transaction with Enhanced Ecommerce?

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-datalayer, enhanced-ecommerce

One of my customers has a problem with Enhanced Ecommerce through GTM.

This customer has two groups of products: 
- Group A: products that my customer distributes directly to their clients
- Group B: product that my customer distributes through a wholesaler.

When a client orders one product from Group A and another produt from Group B, my client receives 2 different orders.

My client wants to be able to measure those transaction orders separately and extract reports from GA.

I have currently considered double push of the "purchase" script on the thankyou page, one for each order with its corresponding products (Group A & Group B).

Do you think it is the best option?

Or would a single generic push of the transaction be best? Using a secondary dimension within the products I could separate it by order-1 (Group A) and order-2 (Group B)?

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You could distinguish them with the “Category” parameter within the scripts then in GA you would segment by category is Product Group A

```
gtag('event', 'purchase', {
  "transaction_id": "24.031608523954162",
  "affiliation": "Google online store",
  "value": 23.07,
  "currency": "USD",
  "tax": 1.24,
  "shipping": 0,
  "items": [
    {
      "id": "P12345",
      "name": "Android Warhol T-Shirt",
      "list_name": "Search Results",
      "brand": "Google",
      "category": "Product Group A",
      "variant": "Black",
      "list_position": 1,
      "quantity": 2,
      "price": '2.0'
    },
    {
      "id": "P67890",
      "name": "Flame challenge TShirt",
      "list_name": "Search Results",
      "brand": "MyBrand",
      "category": "Product Group B",
      "variant": "Red",
      "list_position": 2,
      "quantity": 1,
      "price": '3.0'
    }
  ]
});
```